# Wordpress Login page redirects back to itself

Tags: wordpress, redirect, refresh, http-status-code-302

I’m trying to log in to wordpress dashboard but it redirects back to login page causing 302 error.
I’ve tried all solutions suggested in the internet including clearing caches, deactivating plugins and themes, changing url in wp-confing.php and deleting .htaccess file but none of above did't help… How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Open your domain manager backup your site from cpanel and reinstall wordpress using cpanel. I think it should work

Comment: It's working site made with elementor, how then I can bring back ready pages? @prakash

Comment: You can backup your site on cpanel and reinstall wordpress then restore the backup

Comment: Do you mean only delete database and install wp from scratch?

Comment: No i mean backup database(can be done in cpanel) backup content(also from c panel) and reinstall wordpress